# containerd v1.4+ - How to authenticate by config?

Tags: docker, authentication, registry, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, containerd

I'm using containerd as container engine for my Kubernetes cluster.

I only have access to a shared IP, so the docker-rate-limit is exhausted most of the time.

Therefore, I wanna use my docker account to increase my limit.

But how to configure the docker credentials to use directly in the containerd-service?
I want explicitly to prevent using ImagePullSecrets or using a mirror-registry.

At the moment, I'd work around with the old config style like this

```ini
...
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."docker.io".auth]
          username = "<user>"
          password = "<password>"
...
```

But due to [containerd cri documentation](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md#configure-registry-credentials), this config style is deprecated.

Now I'm wondering, how to use credentials with the new style by using config_Path="/etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io/hosts.toml" and what the syntax of the hosts.toml should look like.

The [containerd hosts.toml documentation](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md) isn't really helpful...

Has somebody worked this out and can provide an example for the hosts.toml?